# Laravel 5.8.9 Auth problem with @error directive - Undefined variable: message

Tags: laravel

i have some problem with Auth - @error directive. I got `"Undefined variable: message"`. Screens below. How can i solve it?

[Error View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x72kV.png)

`Undefined variable: message (View: C:\Users\Kitsune\Desktop\projekty\Norbert\ProjektInzynierski\resources\views\auth\login.blade.php)`

[Login Blade View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQz5e.png)

```
<div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Please, add the code as text, not as an image.

Comment: I don't think your Laravel version supports that; the blog post for the `@error` directive says Laravel 5.8.12, but you're on 5.8.9. Are you able to upgrade that? That or revert to the old approach as seen in: https://laravel-news.com/blade-error-directive

Comment: Upgrade laravel to ^6.0 helped, thanks